# Get nodes value one by one in xslt

Tags: xslt

I am using XSl file in which I am reading values from xml node and creating another xml file. Following is the part of input xml from which I want to read value node one by one.

Input Xml:

```
<Param>
  <RoomsInvs>
<RoomInv>
    <ProvisionalId Id="13-0000000007">13-0000000007</ProvisionalId>
</RoomInv>
<RoomInv>
    <ProvisionalId Id="13-0000000008">13-0000000008</ProvisionalId>
</RoomInv>
  </RoomsInvs>
  <Rooms>
<Room NumberOfRooms="1" RoomId="TLC13-000005" Description="AC DEULEX" Twin="no" SupplierCode="RM" SupplierId="0" PropertyId="" ExtraBed="0" RateBasis="-4" Type="" Index="0">
    <Rate Id="0" Currency="INR" Gross="4990.00" DisplayCurrency="INR" DisplayGross="4990.00" Net="4990.00" Tax="0" STax="" ExtraGuestCharge="0" AdultCount="2" AdultRate="1490.00" ChildCount="0" ChildRate=".00" Description="" Status="Available" AllocationDetails="-" SDisc="" SComm="" SRoomTotal="">
        ieiorkmbjfgngjofmgfoikmfhkjg
    </Rate>
</Room>
<Room NumberOfRooms="2" RoomId="TLC13-000005" Description="AC DEULEX" Twin="no" SupplierCode="RM" SupplierId="0" PropertyId="" ExtraBed="0" RateBasis="-4" Type="" Index="0">
    <Rate Id="0" Currency="INR" Gross="4990.00" DisplayCurrency="INR" DisplayGross="4990.00" Net="4990.00" Tax="0" STax="" ExtraGuestCharge="0" AdultCount="2" AdultRate="1490.00" ChildCount="0" ChildRate=".00" Description="" Status="Available" AllocationDetails="-" SDisc="" SComm="" SRoomTotal="">
        dbfbjsdbfjsdfbkjsdfbklnlnlsdf
    </Rate>
</Room>
  </Rooms>
<Param>
```

Xsl Applied:

```
<Rooms>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="//Rooms/Room" >
<xsl:with-param name ="IdNo" select ="//RoomsInvs/RoomInv"></xsl:with-param>
 </xsl:apply-templates>
</Rooms>

<xsl:template match="Room" >
<xsl:param name="IdNo"/>
<Room>
    <tempID>
    <xsl:value-of select="$IdNo[position()]/ProvisionalId"/>
    </tempID>
    <xsl:copy-of select="Rate"/>
</Room>
```

Output Getting:

```
  <Rooms>
<Room>
    <tempID>13-0000000007</tempID>
    <Rate Id="0" Currency="INR" Gross="4990.00" DisplayCurrency="INR" DisplayGross="4990.00" Net="4990.00" Tax="0" STax="" ExtraGuestCharge="0" AdultCount="2" AdultRate="1490.00" ChildCount="0" ChildRate=".00" Description="" Status="Available" AllocationDetails="-" SDisc="" SComm="" SRoomTotal="">
        ieiorkmbjfgngjofmgfoikmfhkjg
    </Rate>
</Room>
<Room>
    <tempID>13-0000000007</tempID>
    <Rate Id="0" Currency="INR" Gross="4990.00" DisplayCurrency="INR" DisplayGross="4990.00" Net="4990.00" Tax="0" STax="" ExtraGuestCharge="0" AdultCount="2" AdultRate="1490.00" ChildCount="0" ChildRate=".00" Description="" Status="Available" AllocationDetails="-" SDisc="" SComm="" SRoomTotal="">
        dbfbjsdbfjsdfbkjsdfbklnlnlsdf
    </Rate>
</Room>
</Rooms>
```

Output I want:

```
  <Rooms>
<Room>
    <tempID>13-0000000007</tempID>
    <Rate Id="0" Currency="INR" Gross="4990.00" DisplayCurrency="INR" DisplayGross="4990.00" Net="4990.00" Tax="0" STax="" ExtraGuestCharge="0" AdultCount="2" AdultRate="1490.00" ChildCount="0" ChildRate=".00" Description="" Status="Available" AllocationDetails="-" SDisc="" SComm="" SRoomTotal="">
        ieiorkmbjfgngjofmgfoikmfhkjg
    </Rate>
</Room>
<Room>
    <tempID>13-0000000008</tempID>
    <Rate Id="0" Currency="INR" Gross="4990.00" DisplayCurrency="INR" DisplayGross="4990.00" Net="4990.00" Tax="0" STax="" ExtraGuestCharge="0" AdultCount="2" AdultRate="1490.00" ChildCount="0" ChildRate=".00" Description="" Status="Available" AllocationDetails="-" SDisc="" SComm="" SRoomTotal="">
        dbfbjsdbfjsdfbkjsdfbklnlnlsdf
    </Rate>
</Room>
</Rooms>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `position()` inside the predicate (between the `[]` symbols) where it is taking on a different meaning. You should assign `position()` to a variable, and then use the variable. I believe this produces the expected result:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Rooms>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//Rooms/Room">
        <xsl:with-param name="IdNo" select="//RoomsInvs/RoomInv" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </Rooms>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Room">
    <xsl:param name="IdNo" select="/.." />

    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />

    <Room>
      <tempID>
        <xsl:value-of select="$IdNo[$pos]/ProvisionalId" />
      </tempID>
      <xsl:copy-of select="Rate" />
    </Room>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Solution you given is proper but I was wrong. I was not properly mentioned that what I am doing through XSL Now I have edited it.

Comment: Ok, but from your example, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Could you explain it? Or does my sample solve your problem?

Comment: In this problem I am calling one template for some other work this template gives me two nodes in that two nodes I want to get two values of "ProvisionalId" from which one value is for first node of template and another value is for second node of template but I am getting first value for bothe nodes in template. So my question is that how can I avoid the duplication or how can i get seperate value for each of the node returned from template ?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand, but could you provide a sample XML input that corresponds to your updated XSLT? The one you've provided still doesn't contain any `SomeOtherValue` elements.